# How to print a div in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

Net c# website i have an html report is there.Now i want to take a printout of the same.So i used Javascript and its showing only the popup box ,not the content.how to solve this issue.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintDiv() {
            var divToPrint = document.getElementById('widget-content');
            var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=400,location=no,left=200px');
            popupWin.document.open();
            popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
            popupWin.document.close();
        }
         </script>
```

button Click

```
<input type="button" onclick="PrintDiv()" value="Print" />
```

HTML Content

```
 <div class="widget-content">
                    <div class="invoice-content">
                        <div class="invoice-head">
                            <div class="invoice-meta">
                                <%--Invoice <span class="invoice-number">#96558 </span><span class="invoice-date">Date:
                                    2012-07-15</span>--%>
                            </div>
                            <h5 style="margin-left: 40%; height: 20px; font-size: large">
                                Order Form</h5>
                            <div class="invoice-to">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span>Booking Date:<asp:Label ID="dispbookingDate" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
                                        <span>Name<asp:Label TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ID="dispName"></asp:Label></span>
                                        <span>Address:<asp:Label TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ID="dispAddress"></asp:Label></span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="invoice-from">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span>Order No.<asp:Label ID="dispOrderNo" runat="server"></asp:Label></span> <span>
                                        Wedding Date:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="dispWeddingDate"></asp:Label></span>
                                        <span>Malayalam Date:<asp:Label runat="server" ID="dispWeddingMalayam"></asp:Label></span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="style1">
                                            Description
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="style2">
                                            Rs.
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Ps.
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="total-label" colspan="2">
                                            Total:
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="total-amount">
                                            <asp:Label ID="dispTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="total-label" colspan="2">
                                            Adavance:
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="total-amount">
                                            <asp:Label ID="dispAvance" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="total-label" colspan="2">
                                            Balance:
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="total-amount">
                                            <asp:Label ID="dispBalance" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style1">
                                            Auditorium Rent
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style2">
                                            <asp:Label ID="dispRent" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style1">
                                            Dining Hall Rent
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style2">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style1">
                                            Kathir Mandapam
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style2">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style1">
                                            Tables and chairs
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style2">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style1">
                                            Electricity charge for water
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style2">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style1">
                                            Luxuary Tax
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style2">
                                            <asp:Label ID="dispLTax" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style1">
                                            Central Service Tax
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style2">
                                            <asp:Label ID="dispCTax" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                      <%--  <p class="amount-word">
                            Amount in Word: <span>
                                <asp:Label ID="dispAmountWord" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
                        </p>--%>
                    </div>
                     <input type="button" onclick="PrintDiv()" value="Print" />
                </div>
```

Comment: You should consider reformatting the code blocks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript you are searching for the div with id `widget-content`

your code: `var divToPrint = document.getElementById('widget-content');`

but in your html you have `<div class="widget-content">` and it has no id, it only has a class.

So you have 2 options.

**OPTION 1**

Change `class` to `id`

---

**OPTION 2**

Change your javascript to search for the class like so

```
var divToPrint = document.getElementsByClassName('widget-content')
```

**NOTE:** this will return an array of elements with that class, whether theres only one or more.

So in order to select the one you want; assuming there is only 1 div with this class you do like so:

```
var divToPrint = document.getElementsByClassName('widget-content')[0]
```

Comment: Similar problem here.. My print content in Panel not in div. There is no error but unable to print.. suggest me